# Social PopUP - Facebook like. Not showing popup if the user has already liked

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, popup

Is there any way to implement not showing the popup (for Facebook) if the user has already liked the page? Currently in that case the popup is still shown, only with the grayed out "like" button.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this with saving user meta value yes you have to insert user meta key when user like post first time like.

```
     update_user_meta( $user_id, $current_post_id.'_facebook_flag', 'yes' );
```

after that you have to check  this value like...

```
     $user_like_flag = get_user_meta($user_id, $current_post_id.'_facebook_flag, true); 
     if($user_like_flag != 'yes'){
           // show popup
     }
```